# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - AWS and Vercel

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, vercel

I have a small problem with my API that I use with Express JS, I deployed on AWS and Vercel the problem is the same except for Heroku.

All my GET POST routes work fine. except when I want to upload a video on my frontend in REACT I have this error that you see in the photo.

I tried all the possible parameters with the configuration of the cors.

Everything works locally
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **POST request**  giving you `413 HTTP error` that  occurs when the size of a client’s request exceeds the server’s file size limit.in your case the size of the video you want to uploded bigger than the size of the server limit

Comment: Yes Thank you that's exactly it, my file must not exceed 4.5 mb

Comment: https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-bypass-vercel-body-size-limit-serverless-functions

Comment: Happy you figure out not only why you're getting this  error but also  how to solve 